# Structuring a basic app iOS app - single view - best practice

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, json

I am currently working on a single view app that does the following:

1. Grabs users location using CoreLocation
2. Sends their lon/lat to an API
3. Returns tide data as JSON
4. Dive in to objects and keys within the JSON to return: tide levels, locations, etc and display them via text labels.

I have the majority of this working, but it is more so crammed in to `viewDidLoad` - I am trying to see the best way to organize something like this up. Would I break it in to different methods such as:

- setTideData
- displayTideData

Or would it be more broken down than that? (And yes im sure it all depends on the details too). I would be displaying probably 8-10 different stats on the view.

Things like

- On `viewDidLoad` do I grab the users location or do it prior on viewDidAppear, etc
- Would I then call my displayTideData method inside of viewDidLoad

Just looking for some type of general best practice, was trying to scan for some items but nothing was what I was looking for.

EDIT: Here is an example of my returned data -- https://gist.github.com/ryancoughlin/8043604

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is prior to `viewDidAppear`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty much a matter of preference and style, but you could simplify your logic in a number of ways by separating certain parts into their own classes, eg:

- You could use something like [JSON model](http://www.jsonmodel.com/) to deserialize the data into a class, and access it in a more convenient way
- Loading the data and deserializing could be handled in a different class that would only return the object with the data you need
- Etc.

It's hard to give a better advice without reviewing your code directly, but this should give you some pointers how to simplify things.

EDIT: A bit of code example how to separate the the deserialization and data handling into a custom object:

```
- (id)initWithJSON:(NSDictionary *)JSON
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        self.gender = [JSON objectForKey:@"gender"];
        self.email = [JSON objectForKey:@"email"];
        self.firstName = [JSON objectForKey:@"first_name"];
        self.lastName = [JSON objectForKey:@"last_name"];
        self.personId = [[JSON objectForKey:@"person_id"] integerValue];
    }

    return self;
}
```

You would then simply create an object with the data like this:

```
Person *person = [[Person alloc] initWithJSON:JSON];
```

and simply access whatever data you need in a cleaner way:

```
self.myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name: %@", person.firstName];
```

Comment: Great, thank you. I figured it would be different based on style, etc. But didnt know if there was a general "proper" way to do so. I would have one class that does all the calling to request the JSON and then access that object among my other classes?

Comment: In regards to your second bullet point. As mentioned I have about 8 data points I want to display. Tucked away in various keys nested in the JSON. Would each key I want to display be a method or do I have 1 method that returns a new object or string for each piece I want to display?

Comment: I would make a single object with 8 properties corresponding to those 8 data points. The object would be created and updated when you fetch the new data. JSON model up there does everything for you automatically, but it might be an overkill if there is a single object and writing your own deserializer is rather simple. For a similar case, I had an init method that had one input parameter - a JSON dictionary in my custom object, so I created a custom object in a cleaner way: MyObject *object = [[MyObject alloc] initWithJSON:JSON];

Comment: I would then loop through and add the keys for each one I need in its own object? Currently, it returns the correct JSON and it works, its just alot of info. At some point I would end up with 8 strings converted from a dictionary or array to update my labels right?

Comment: In its own property actually. I'll update the answer above with some code of a custom initializer for a custom class derived from JSON data.

Comment: Gotcha, interesting, thank you for that. I updated my question with the data i am using. it would be modified from that since I would need to access nested values ```tide.tideInfo.tideSummary``` - which is an array with one object?

Comment: If you're sure there will always be one object in the array, you are free to omit the array during the deserialization :).

Comment: I would have to access that as NSArray correct? I wish my data was organized as your example :) Since various pieces of data are nested, I would end up with multiple objects right?

Comment: Yes, that would be the case. I suggest you do look into the JSON model a bit more (your data set is a bit more complex than I initially thought), as it will handle the deserialization more or less automatically.

Comment: Will do! I am currently using UNIRest and tried AFNetworking previously. Do you recommend JSON model over them?

Comment: I actually use both AFNetworking and JSON model, but if you have a simple app as described, I think JSON model's networking should be enough for you.

Comment: How much would change if I had various values I wanted to pull that were nested? ```tide.tideSummary.maxheight``` -- ```tide.tideInfo.tideSite``` - for a quick example. Your example works  great for a single. Would I have a class/object for each?

Comment: You can nest as many classes as you want, meaning, one class can have another class as a property and you should be able to access it the way you described with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a Massive View Controller, which is a bad thing. Try to reorganise your code so you have a fat model and a skinny controller. Controllers should only be responsible for creating and refreshing the view, bootstrapping the model and updating the model based on user interaction. Some possible model objects:

- Fetching data from the server.
- Parser for converting JSON objects into typed objects (thus encapsulating the knowledge of the JSON structure).
- A simple interface (e.g. one object) for your view controller to pull data from and push data to.

Your model should contain all the business logic for the app.

Comment: Ok great, thanks for this! I would have ```tideInformation.h``` and it would do what you said above. It would then contains the objects that I can set in my ```tideView.h``` and set my ```label.text```

Comment: I would end up with numerous strings that would be accessed across both files? Then display and set my labels?

Comment: Yes, creating a TideInformation class sounds like a good start. I'm not sure what you mean "strings that would be accessed across both files". If you're referring to JSON dictionary keys then I would encapsulate them inside the TideInformation class. So instead of have a dictionary and strings defining for the keys you'd have properties on TideInformation. This approach means that the details of the JSON are hidden from the controller.

Comment: Ok great. I am using JSONModel. So I would have a bunch of properties that relate to they key I want to display? inside of my TideInformation class? I posted my returned JSON above in my question if that helps give context. Then to access that cross class I would import and set up a delegate? or?